# Could i use google firebase realtime database as a normal database?

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need my app to use some realtime dataflow and also some static data , if it wise to use firebase database for both , or it's better to split the data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use FirebaseDatabse to suit your 'static' needs. Basically, if you need your database only for some static data, use the FirebaseDatabase's REST API. As other APIs allows you to handle listeners, offline capabilities and some other realtime data, the Rest API doesn't includes any of these. Which make this light weight. Use the REST API with Volley, and you can use FirebaseDatabase like a real static database with no real time functionalities.